# Replication problem - Conflict Resolving

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

(sqlserver 2008)

We have various subscribers and one publishers. We have a table which keeps track of inventory. Now, this is what happens - a user makes some changes on the subscriber to the inventory table(column BalanceQty is modified), and another user makes changes on the same table and column in Publisher. So, when synchronization happens, a conflict is raised. But, the publisher wins and the wrong quantity is reflected in the database. How should we tackle this scenario? The synchronization should take both values in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the most recent update to the column value will win.  Depending on your business rules, you could use one of the provided conflict resolvers in SQL Server (such as the "Subscriber Always Wins" resolver).

The provided resolvers are described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152573.aspx